# Softlayer API getAccountBackupHistory with Python giving SoftLayer_Exception_Public

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

First of all I would like to mention I'm very new to cloud computing and Python.
I hope you guys are more helpful than the softlayer service desk.

At the moment I'm have a difficult time understanding there Python API.
I have a couple servers running and each server has evault agent running. The agents create on regular basis a backup of my server(s). The evault agents are running for a couple of months now, so I have some historical data.

What I would like, is to create a Python script that checks (daily) if the backup was successful. But unfortunately I can't access the "getAccountBackupHistory" method from the "Account " service.

The "getAccountBackupHistory" expects 3 parameters but I don't know where to add these.

- [Softlayer Account Service API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account)
- [Softlayer getAccountBackHistory Method](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAccountBackupHistory)

I also searched there forum in the hope to found something similar but I didn't find anything useful.

- Softlayer Forum General
- Softlayer Forum Implementation

This is my script so far:

```
import SoftLayer
import datetime,time
from SoftLayer import utils
import pprint

usr_name="my_username"
api="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=usr_name, api_key=api)

dt_now=datetime.datetime.now()
dt_end=str(dt_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
dt_start=str((dt_now-datetime.timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

#First attempt
obj=client.call("Account","getAccountBackupHistory",dt_start,dt_end,"success")


#Second attempt
obj=client["Account"]
webcc=obj.getAccountBackupHistory(dt_start,dt_end,"success")
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Error Occured. Unable to get account backup history.
```

P.S: The account I'm using has admin rights 
Any advice is welcome
Cheers,
Eredjar

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is an issue with [SoftLayer_Account::getAccountBackupHistory](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAccountBackupHistory).

However, if you want to check, if the backups are created successfully from their agents, you can try the following Python script:

```
"""
This script retrieves an account's associated EVault storage volumes.
Also it retrieves the "agentStatuses" and "backupJobDetails" information from them.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getEvaultNetworkStorage
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer username and apiKey
usr_name = "set me"
api = "set me"

# Declare the API client.
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=usr_name, api_key=api)

# Declare an object mask, to get agentStatuses and backupJobDetails information
object_mask = "mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[agentStatuses, backupJobDetails]"

try:
    obj = client["SoftLayer_Account"].getEvaultNetworkStorage(mask=object_mask)
    pprint.pprint(obj)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error: faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but how did you know to use the "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6" ? Because when I look at "SoftLayer_Account" I can't see this under the data type (Relational or Local Properties)

Comment: As you can see, the SoftLayer_Account::getEvaultNetworkStorage method retrieves a SoftLayer_Network_Storage objects, this is the generic container for the "Network Storage Objects". 

So, we need to specify the type of objects that we wish to retrieve in the object mask, in order to get a clear idea about it, take a look [Object Mask](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks) "Type" section. Also, we can review the documentation about Evaul: [SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6).

Comment: I think it can be something confused, but I can recommend to review the [SLDN documentation](http://sldn.softlayer.com/). Also you can see the objects that SoftLayer API is handling [SLDN datatypes](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes)